# How to use numpy.einsum to blend two frames?

Tags: python, numpy, mask, alphablending, numpy-einsum

## Goal

I want to use [numpy.einsum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to blend two frames together. The reason I really want to use einsum is because I would like to be able to understand how it works and how it can be applied.

## Problem

- I have two frames, a "red" frame and a "green" frame.
- I also have two masks, one with the "left-top" quadrant set to true and another one with the "right-bottom" set to true.

Now by multiplying the "red" frame with the "left-top" mask, multiplying the "green" frame with the "right-bottom" mask and summing the result I want to create a new frame. This new frame then has a red left-top, a green right-bottom and the rest (right-top, left-bottom) black.

## Example

Here I provide an example which does exactly what I want without using einsum.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

height = 2
width = 2

# A "red" RGB frame
r_frame = np.stack([
    np.full(shape=(height, width), fill_value=255),
    np.zeros(shape=(height, width)),
    np.zeros(shape=(height, width))
], axis=-1).astype(int)

# A "green" RGB frame
g_frame = np.stack([
    np.zeros(shape=(height, width)),
    np.full(shape=(height, width), fill_value=255, dtype=int),
    np.zeros(shape=(height, width))
], axis=-1).astype(int)

# Left-top mask
lt_mask = np.zeros(shape=(height, width), dtype=int)
lt_mask[:height//2, :width//2] = 1

# Right-bottom mask
rb_mask = np.zeros(shape=(height, width), dtype=int)
rb_mask[height//2:, width//2:] = 1

# Frame with a "red" left-top, a "green" right-bottom and the rest "black"
frame = r_frame * lt_mask[:, :, np.newaxis] + g_frame * rb_mask[:, :, np.newaxis]

plt.imshow(frame)
plt.show()
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

## Stuck

I am stuck at the following step. I manage to multiply a single frame with a single mask, but I cannot sum the result.

```py
# The same frame, now using einsum in two steps
frame = np.einsum('ijk,ij->ijk', r_frame, lt_mask) + np.einsum('ijk,ij->ijk', g_frame, rb_mask)

plt.imshow(frame)
plt.show()

# The same frame, now using einsum in one step
# ???
```

Comment: `einsum` is a multidimensional sum-of-products function, a generalization of `dot` or matrix-product.  You are doing the products.  To do the `sum` part you'd have to `stack` the 2 frames and the 2 masks.  And then do something like `einsum('hijk,hij->ijk,frames,masks)`

Comment: Ah thanks, what made it click for me was the phrasing of "multidimensional sum-of-products function". That helped!